# How can I divide line from input file in two parts and then compare it to the two column data of database table in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

Given a text file, how would I go about reading an particular digits in line .

Say, I have a file 123.txt. How would I go about reading line number and store first 5 digits in different variable and next 6 digits to another variable.

All I've seen is stuff involving storing the entire text file as a String array . but there are some complications: The text file is enormously huge and the machine that the application I'm coding isn't exactly a top-notch system. Speed isn't the top priority, but it is definitely a major issue.

// Please Help here

```
// Want to compare data of input file with database table columns.
// How to split data in to parts
// Access that split data later for comparison.

// Data in input file is like,
//

// 016584824684000000000000000+

// 045787544574000000000000000+

// 014578645447000000000000000+

// 047878741489000000000000000+ and so on..

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("F:\\123.txt"); // Input file

// How can I divide lines from input file in 2 parts (For ex. 01658 and 4824684) and save it in variable so that I can use it for comparing later.                         

string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BVI"].ConnectionString;
                        cnn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
                        cnn.Open();

// So I want to compare first 5 digits of all lines of input file (ex. 01658)with Transit_ID and next 6 digits with Client_Account and then export matching rows in excel file.

sql = "SELECT Transit_ID AS TransitID, Client_Account AS AccountNo FROM TCA_CLIENT_ACCOUNT WHERE Transit_ID = " //(What should I put here to comapare with first 5 digits of all lines of input file)" AND Client_Account = " ??" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`Substring(int32, int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the appropriate values like this:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("F:\\123.txt");
List<string> first = new List<string>();
List<string> second = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{ 
    first.Add(line.Substring(0, 5));
    second.Add(line.Substring(6, 6));
}
```

Though Eric's answer is much cleaner. This was just a quick and dirty proof of concept using your sample data. You should definitely use the `using` statement and `StreamReader` as he suggested.

`first` will contain the first 5 digits from each element in `lines`, and `second` will contain the next 6 digits.

Then to build your SQL, you'd do something like this;

```
sql = "SELECT Transit_ID AS TransitID, Client_Account AS AccountNo FROM TCA_CLIENT_ACCOUNT WHERE Transit_ID = @TransitId AND Client_Account = @ClientAcct");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransitId", first[i]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientAcct", second[i]);

    //execute your command and validate results
}
```

That will loop N times and run a command for each of the values in `lines`.

Comment: This does not help with `Given a text file, how would I go about reading an particular digits in line`

Comment: @EricJ.  the question was more so "how to divide a line into two parts"; he already successfully read the lines from the file (albeit not up to his performance standards) per this comment in his code `// How can I divide lines from input file in 2 parts (For ex. 01658 and 4824684) and save it in variable so that I can use it for comparing later.` That's the question I was answering. Though I suppose I should change my post to just assign `lines` using the file in his question.

Comment: But, How can I compare both with column name of table later ?               sql = "SELECT Transit_ID AS TransitID, Client_Account AS AccountNo FROM TCA_CLIENT_ACCOUNT WHERE Transit_ID = " //(What should I put here to comapare with first 5 digits of all lines of input file)" AND Client_Account = " ??" );

Comment: @NikunjVala It looks like you just want something along the lines of "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = first", right? Look up a tutorial on `Parameterized Queries` for C# and do that. Or simply concatenate your variables into your sql string there. But you really shouldn't do that because it's dangerous.

Comment: @sab669 ; Yeah.. I want to do like that where transit_ID = 'First' and Client_Account = 'Second' . But the values of first and second doesn't retrieve here.

Comment: @NikunjVala Editted my post with a sample on how to build a parameterized query.

Comment: for (int k = 0; k <lines.Count; k++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransitId", first[k]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientAcct", second[k]);                      
                    }  // Here at  k<lines.count , it shows error as '<' operator can not applied to operands of type int or method group

Comment: So now how can I export those values to excel file. I have done this. what should I edit in this ?                                                                                     sql = "SELECT Transit_ID AS TransitID, Client_Account AS AccountNo FROM TCA_CLIENT_ACCOUNT WHERE Transit_ID = @TransitId AND Client_Account = @ClientAcct";
                     for (int k = 0; k < lines.Count(); i++)
                    {
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransitId", trasitId[k]);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientAcct", accNumber[k]);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

> All I've seen is stuff involving storing the entire text file as a String array

Large text files should be processed by streaming one line at a time so that you don't allocate a large amount of memory needlessly

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
{
    string s;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        // How would I go about reading line number and store first 5 
        // digits in different variable and next 6 digits to another variable.
        string first = s.Substring(0, 5);
        string second = s.Substring(6, 6);
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "..and next 6 digits to another variable." I think OP ultimately only cares about the first 11 digits per element in the `lines` collection, where as your `string second` will have all of the remaining data on the line since you just use `Substring(int)` that time.

Comment: Also, what's the point of assigning `String.Empty` to `s` on the first line in the `using` statement?

Comment: @sab669: Good point, I limited the second string to 6 characters.  `what's the point of assigning String.Empty to s on the first line in the using statement?` High-quality MSDN example :-)  Edited it.  At least they bothered with a using statement in that example.

Comment: Oh! I didn't even see the link below your code snippet. I wasn't sure if it was just some weird 'trick' to get around a compiler warning thinking you're trying to use an un-assigned variable, or something.

Comment: But, How can I compare both with column name of table later ?                                          sql = "SELECT Transit_ID AS TransitID, Client_Account AS AccountNo FROM TCA_CLIENT_ACCOUNT WHERE Transit_ID = " //(What should I put here to comapare with first 5 digits of all lines of input file)" AND Client_Account = " ??" );